# C are label addresses across function calls the same

Tags: c, gcc, goto

when i store the address of a label with GCCs labels as values extension, are they the same across differently deep calls?

```
void *label = NULL;

int test() {
  if (label == NULL) {
    label = &&label_l;
  } else {
    goto *label;
  }
  
  return(test() + 1);
  
  label_l:
  return(0);
}
```

Will this work, even if the label was set in a different stack frame?

Comment: this code will not compile. Post working code. Put some more effort.

Comment: Once you have fixed the error in the code (`label_l` isn't actually a label), this is quite an interesting question... Will a pointer to a label stay the same over multiple calls? I would say yes, because the functions doesn't move around in memory once loaded.

Comment: `void*` is compatible to any data pointer. Labels are no data objects. Is there some real problem behind?

Comment: Of course, it assumes that you won't attempt to go to the label using the pointer from another function.

Comment: I wonder how anyone might set up the stack frame correctly to match environment of that function.

Comment: With all this said, why are you doing something like this? What is the real underlying problem this is supposed to solve? If it's just plain curiosity, then that's okay but please [edit] your question to state so. Otherwise please ask about your actual problem directly instead (otherwise this is an [XY problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XY_problem)).

Comment: https://godbolt.org/z/fWMs3rz1z I think it is self explanatory

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude label is only assembler label. variable label is local to the current execution scope. It will simply jump to the same place in the code without any change in the stack.

Comment: `even if the label was set in a different stack frame?` What do you mean by "different stack frame"?

Comment: @KamilCuk OP means different invocations of the function, i.e. in the example `label` is set on the initial call of the function and then read in the subsequent recursive call.

Comment: With stack frame I mean a different call depth. This is just an example where the function call storing the label isn't the same jumping to the lab

Comment: @Gerhardh: [GCC documents `void *` as a suitable type for storing addresses of labels.](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Labels-as-Values.html)

Comment: Please, don't tag GCC specific extensions as 'C', if you don't want to receive this kind of comments.  You are trying to extend the reachability of your question far beyond its scope.  By the way, GCC specific extensions are very well documented in the GCC manual.  Read it first to ask what you can do and what you cannot.

Comment: @LuisColorado: The text for the C tag suggests it may be used with other tags and statements to indicate it is about variants from the standard. Also, the question asked is not clearly answered in the GCC documentation about labels as values.

Comment: The text of the C tag doesn't suggest that to me.  It talks about C language specific issues and  Standards, not specific compiler implementations or extensions (as this question is about) There are other tags for that (like GCC in this case)

Comment: @LuisColorado: By the way, C as implemented with extensions is C as defined in the ISO 9899 standard. The standard defines extensions to be allowed (C 2018 4 6: “A conforming implementation may have extensions…”) and makes them an integral part of the definition of a “conforming program” as distinct from a “strictly conforming program.” Using extensions is a conforming part of ISO 9899 C.

Comment: All standards allow for extension or implementation defined issues... but one thing is to say that this forum is made to talk about C and the standard... and another different to say that anything that departs from the standard is well received.  I'm just telling that there's already a tag (GCC) to discuss GCC extensions to C, which are clearly not part of the standard.

Comment: @LuisColorado: No, not all standards allow for extensions. Some are intended be strict specifications so that programs using them run identically on all implementations. These are important distinctions. In C, it is an important feature that extensions are welcomed. This was critical to its success as a language that can be ported to many different platforms—rather than just making programs portable, it made programmers portable by letting them use their knowledge of C in a wide variety of platforms even though the C implementations varied greatly.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> are they the same across differently deep calls?

Generally, yes. From [the documentation](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Labels-as-Values.html):

> The &&foo expressions for the same label might have different values if the containing function is inlined or cloned. If a program relies on them being always the same, `__attribute__((__noinline__,__noclone__))` should be used to prevent inlining and cloning. If &&foo is used in a static variable initializer, inlining and cloning is forbidden.

In your program it is not used in a static variable initializer, so it is possible that your function gets inlined or duplicated and the label will jump to different function - make sure it does not happen. (But even if you would do `static void *label = &&label_l` I would still add `__attribute__((__noinline__,__noclone__))` to protect against later refactoring).

One real life example: [protothreads](http://dunkels.com/adam/pt/) may use [labels as values](https://github.com/Akagi201/protothreads/blob/master/include/lc-addrlabels.h#L81) to store the case statement to jump to.

Overall, do not use labels as values. If you intent to use it, prefer to only use it for automatic local variables. The code you presented looks like an invitation for unmaintainable spaghetti code.

> even if the label was set in a different stack frame?

Yes, stack frame does not matter. We are living on [(ok, "modified") Hardvard architecture](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Harvard_architecture), so what is in memory is separate and code location does not change.